# Gmail API Android Quickstart Example Not Working

Tags: android, gmail-api

I want to use gmail api in one of my android app.
For that i am following this link : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android

I have followed all the instructions as given in the link.

When i ran the app Choose an account screen comes.

[image]

When i select an account and clicks on OK then again same Choose an account screens opens.
Strangely if i click on CANCEL also the same Choose an account screen reappears.

I have checked logcat also there is no error.

I have tested this app on emulator as well as on real device.

The issue remains the same.

My **build.gradle** file is showing:

```
 minSdkVersion 15
 targetSdkVersion 23
```

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using marshmallow to test this.
The reason for this problem is that your app is not granted permissions to read contacts(on its own).So you either need to enable it manually from app settings or implement that permission grant api introduced in marshmallow.
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

ps-Just noticed we've got a common surname :P

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

Comment: These permissions are not sufficient for marshmallow. You need to implement runtime permissions to read contacts.Or manually grant access from app settings(if you just want to test)

Comment: How to integrate the code explained in the link given by you with the existing gmail api android starter code?

Comment: In just a sample .I wont suggest to do it.Its better to go to app settings and enable contacts permission and implement it once you understand the api code fully.

Comment: I made the change through app settings. The authorization screen is now coming but after allowing permission now i am getting 403 forbidden error. Access not configured. The Api (Gmail Api) is not enabled for your project. But strangely its enabled in developer console.

Comment: You need to properly configure it.Probably you didnt enter sha1 code or entered wrong one